# Bad looking UILabel - missing anti-alias?

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xib

I have a problem with UILabel in monotouch project. UILabels looks like their are missing anti-alias.
UILabels are located in standard UIView inside UITabController (created in IB, not from code).

What can i check?

Comment: Check your UILabel's frame. You may have entered a float value that is not pixel perfect (like 1.5 instead of 1.0). It can happen if you are calculating your label position and use division.

Answer (score 3):

When you are positioning elements you need to make sure that you setup the frame with whole numbers. If you do not you will end up with blurry text or images.

I have run into this issue many times while dynamically creating and placing items on a view.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this article: https://nshipster.com/cggeometry/#integrating-rectangles

> **Integrating Rectangles**
>
> It’s generally a good idea for all `CGRect` values to be rounded to the nearest whole point. Fractional values can cause the frame to be drawn on a pixel boundary. Because pixels are atomic units, a fractional value causes drawing to be averaged over the neighboring pixels. The result: blurry lines that don’t look great.
>
> The `integral` property takes the `floor` each origin value and the `ceil` each size value. This ensures that your drawing code aligns on pixel boundaries crisply.

When setting `view.frame`, try to use `someFrame.integral` to set.